# Edits Server Error 500

Tags: .htaccess, facebook-share, clean-url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news news.php [NC,L]
```

Would appreciate any help on how to address this. I have created a `.htaccess` file for my site in order to simplify its URLs. The entire .htaccess reads as follows (*and works as desired*):

```
RewriteEngine on
```

The only issue I'm facing now is that clicking on it generates a Server Error 500 page instead of the facebook share window.

What can I do to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

You should use **end anchor** in your patterns and turn `MultiViews` off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-z]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Without end anchor `^news` pattern will also match `news.php` and cause infinite looping and eventually 500 (internal server error).

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log and see what the error is there

Comment: the error.log doesnt seem to give any corresponding errors: the last in the log: [Mon Feb 15 07:37:03.244715 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7708:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.`                                                                             On the other hand the full server error message is: `The website encountered an error while retrieving https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexperiment%2Fprefinalkoh%2Fnews%3Fid%3D6. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.`

Comment: From another SO q thread found that By default, PHP does NOT log these errors - so will have to take some steps to enable internal server logging. hold on.

Comment: have set `display_errors = On` `display_startup_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`, but doesnt seem to generate error log for this issue. any way to guess what the 500 error issue could be caused by?

Comment: That is for PHP errors and this 500 is Apache error. You should contact your hosting admin to figure out where is `error.log` located

Comment: I already found the log - that's where i got the last error from: Mon Feb 15 07:37:03.244715 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7708:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.` but it has no relation to error 500

Comment: would appreciate if you could either continue the thread of the comments - or remove ur answer - so i can reissue this question. i appreciate the time you have taken so far and can understand that you may not want to take this thread forward. in which case it would help if i could at least reissue this question to cast for more possible solutions.

Comment: I have already told you the precise instruction to either check the correct `error.log` or contact your hosting admin if you cannot get it yourself.

Comment: Like i said, I have checked the correct error.log and this is on localhost.

Comment: To check whether it is correct log file try putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. It should also write a precise error message in the error.log file

Comment: The browser gave the following error: `Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15`

Comment: The errorlog gave this: `C:/xampp/htdocs/experiment/PrefinalKoH/.htaccess: Invalid command 'SADasdDS', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/experiment/prefinalkoh/news`

Comment: No reference in the log to the server error 500 as far as i can see; though it is referred to in the browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103526/discussion-between-anubhava-and-agni-scribe).